# How to do pattern matching with trivia (Common Lisp/sbcl)?

Tags: pattern-matching, common-lisp

I want to use the [trivia](https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia) library and I am using SBCL.

I want to be able to match a Scheme expression:

```
(match '(let ((n 2)) (* n 2))
  ((letp a b) (list a)))

(defun letp (exp)
  (and (lisp exp) (equal (car exp) 'let)))
```

I have tried to create my own type:

```
(match '(let ((n 2)) (* n 2))
  ((letp a b) (list a)))

(defun let-p (exp)
  (and (lisp exp) (equal (car exp) 'let)))

(deftype letp ()
  `(satisfies let-p))
```

I have done it like this:

```
(match '(let ((n 2)) (+ n 1))
  ((guard x (list-p x)) (car (cdr x))))
```

The above works but I want something cleaner.

Thanks

Comment: Check out trivia's wiki: https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia/wiki/Type-Based-Destructuring-Patterns#type-pattern-satisfies-pattern

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to match on a list that starts with `let`, you can do:

```lisp
(trivia:match '(let ((n 2)) (* n 2)) 
  ((list 'let a b) (list a)))
```

Comment: @chez93 Note that the LIST pattern clause matches only a list of fixed length. Use LIST* pattern to match a list of flexible length. Read: https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia/wiki/Type-Based-Destructuring-Patterns#list-list-pattern